# Elixir skip if nil

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am currently trying to iterate through a collection from Mongo. To do this, I am using this regex to filter through that collection. There are some instances where the regex returns nil, in which it breaks the `List.first` because, well, there is nothing in the list. That causes issues later down the line.

I come from Ruby where I could do a `next unless recipient` or use the lonely operator `List&.first` and go from there. How can I go about doing this in Elixir? I'm mainly interested in skipping the current iteration if the value of the recipient is nil.

```rb
recipient =
  Regex.run(~r/(?<=recipient-).+\/*/, engagement["_id"])
  |> List.first()
  |> String.split("/")
  |> List.first()
```

Comment: If you share your input data we could suggest a better approach the uses binary pattern matching rather than regex.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, looks like you need start use `case` blocks, eg:

```erlang
case Regex.run(~r/(?<=recipient-).+\/*/, engagement["_id"]) do
    nil -> IO.puts "Skip List.first for Regex.run"
    out -> out |> List.first |> String.split("/") |> List.first
end
```

OR

```erlang
Regex.run(~r/(?<=recipient-).+\/*/, engagement["_id"]) |>
case  do
    nil -> IO.puts "Skip List.first for Regex.run"
    out -> out |> List.first |> String.split("/") |> List.first
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a case statement, you can use the head of a function clause to match the result of the regex, i.e. `nil` or the match:

```
defmodule A do
  def go() do
    Enum.each(["a/x", "c", "b/x"], fn str ->
      Regex.run(~r{(a|b)/x}, str, capture: :first)
      |> handle_recipient
    end)
  end

  defp handle_recipient(nil), do: :no_match  #does nothing
  defp handle_recipient([match]) do
    match
    |> String.split("/") 
    |> List.first()
    |> IO.inspect()

  end

end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex "a.ex"
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> A.go
"a"
"b"
:ok

iex(2)>
```

It sounds like you may want to use [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) to filter your collection:

```
defmodule A do
  def go() do
    Enum.reduce(["a/x", "c", "b/x"], [], fn str, acc ->
      Regex.run(~r{(a|b)/*}, str, capture: :first)
      |> handle_recipient(acc)
    end)
  end

  defp handle_recipient(nil, acc), do: acc
  defp handle_recipient([match], acc) do
    result = match
             |> String.split("/")
             |> List.first
    [result|acc]
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex "a.ex"
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> A.go
["b", "a"]
```

You can also write that using [for](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1):

```
defmodule A do
  def go() do
    for str <- ["a/x", "c", "b/x"], reduce: [] do 
      acc -> Regex.run(~r{(a|b)/x}, str, capture: :first)
             |> handle_recipient(acc)
    end
  end

  defp handle_recipient(nil, acc), do: acc  
  defp handle_recipient([match], acc) do
    result = match
             |> String.split("/") 
             |> List.first()
    [result|acc]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Use [`for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) comprehension filtering out unwanted input (everything that is not a list, having a binary head)

```rb
recipient =
  for [match | _] when is_binary(match) <-
      Regex.run(~r/(?<=recipient-).+\/*/, engagement["_id"]),
    do: match |> String.split("/") |> List.first()
```

---

As per documentation for [`Regex.run/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html?#run/3), it returns the type

```
nil | [binary()] | [{integer(), integer()}]
```

That said, one might use [`List.wrap/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html?#wrap/1) to produce an empty list out of `nil`.

```rb
recipient =
  ~r/(?<=recipient-).+\/*/
  |> Regex.run(engagement["_id"])
  |> List.wrap()
  |> List.first()
  |> String.split("/")
  |> List.first()
```

---

Unfortunately, it would then blow up on `String.split/2` down the pipeline.

That said, one might resort to [`Regex.scan/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#scan/3) instead of `Regex.run/3` that *always* returns a list.

```rb
recipient =
  ~r/(?<=recipient-).+\/*/
  |> Regex.scan(engagement["_id"])
  |> List.first()
  |> List.first() # to get to the first capture
  |> String.split("/")
  |> List.first()
```

---

But all this looks like an XY problem. You stated

> *I’m mainly interested in skipping the current iteration if the value of the recipient is `nil`.*

That is impossible out of the box, but there are many workarounds.

- [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#reduce/3) with a reducer having two clauses
- [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#map/2) followed by [`Enum.reject/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#reject/2)
- [`for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) comprehension filtering out `nil`s

I would vote for the latter.

```rb
recipient =
  for [match | _] when is_binary(match) <- Regex.run(~r/(?<=recipient-).+\/*/, engagement["_id"]),
  do: match |> String.split("/") |> List.first()
```